Unable to change Facebook campaign status back to ACTIVE using API despite success response
I'm trying to change a campaign status using the Facebook Marketing API as documented here.
I managed to change the campaign status to PAUSED, but I can't change it back to ACTIVE, even though the API response indicates success.
Here is the API request I'm making:
https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/{campaign_id}?access_token={token}&status=ACTIVE
The response I get is:
{
  "success": true
}

However, the campaign status remains paused. Has anyone encountered this issue or know why the status isn't updating despite the success response?
Additional details:

I used the same approach to pause the campaign, and it worked perfectly.

The access token and campaign ID are correct.


Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Looks like you need this url
curl -X POST https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/act_{acct-id}/campaigns/{campaign_id}?access_token={token}&status=ACTIVE


Thanks for the suggestion, but I already tried that URL and it gives me the error Unknown path component

Did you input your account id like act-1234/?

Yes, that is how I entered my account ID. In fact, I have already made a question about it here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78573355/how-to-resolve-unknown-path-components-error-when-updating-facebook-campaign-s

Interestingly, this page says you can't update campaigns. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/campaigns/v19.0

I know you said you updated it to PAUSED, so that's kind of strange. Not sure what the solution is. Sorry
